# Can't signup for Google Cloud free account: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-BSBBF-01]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to signup for a Google Cloud free trial, I get the following error after the page which checks your details and payment method: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-BSBBF-01]

On this page it shows my payment profile which is correct and works for other Google services such as google Express etc.

Comment: Are you using a prepaid card or a credit one? I can tell, you can use only the latter to sign up for the GCP free-tier.

Comment: It is a credit card unfortunately, so not that!

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation, to sign up for the 12-month, $300 free trial, a ***credit card or bank account*** is needed so Google can verify your identity.
You will not be charged or billed during free trial.

Here is the [**link**](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions) where you can check this information.

Comment: this worked for me... PayPal payment would not let me continue after a few tries... after reading this i used a card and it worked

Comment: It literally doesn't support the format for my bank account number. (From Netherlands btw)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely that you are using a prepaid card, which G Cloud unfortunately does not accept.

Answer (score 0):

My old address was listed on my payments profile. I created a new profile with the correct address and this solved the issue.

[After going around in circles, it appears my old address could only be updated by contacting Google directly despite their online instructions to the contrary. Instead of waiting to speak to Google, I just created a new profile.]